# Reading in own function from a pipe line by line and approaching the whole file as one entity at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

Is it possible to read from a pipe line by line and have access to the whole file as one entity, let's say for grep, at the same time?

```
function()
{ 
while read data 
do
# processing line by line, using $data 
grep "string" WHOLE_FILE | ...
# processing 
done
}
```

`cat some_file | function | ...`

Thank you

Comment: Running `grep` on the entire file once for each line might be expensive. What does your actual code look like? There may be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not implicitly, but

```
{ echo some_file; cat some_file; } | function | ...
```

with

```
function () {
    read filename
    while read data; do
        grep "string" $filename | ...
    done
}
```

should do what you want.

If standard input is connected directly to a file, you might be able to use `readlink` on a file such as `/proc/self/fd/0` (in Linux) to get the name of the file opened on standard input. However, standard input may come from a pipe, which may come from an arbitrary program writing directly to the pipe, rather than an actual file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what to do if I don't know the file name, there can be many pipes, 10, 20, or there is no file at all, just output from some unix utility. Can I somehow in my function access the file descriptor same as read does it and throws it to grep?

Comment: I think you need to post your actual code. A key difference between a stream (as provided on standard input) and a file is that you can seek backwards on a file (or start over), while a stream only lets you move forward: once you've read something from a stream, it's gone and you can't read it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement that function as

```
foo() {
    while read data; do
        grep "$data" $1
    done < $1
}
```

and use it like this

```
foo filename
```